# Do Struts2 action names allow space?

Tags: url, struts2, action, special-characters

In struts2, is it possible to have an action name with a space?

I'm using the RegexPatternMatcher

```
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

My action is defined as

```
<action name="/users/{username}"
        method="execute"
        class="com.test.UserAction">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">.test.user</result>
</action>
```

When I try a url like, `http://localhost:8080/users/a%20space`
The a%20space is set as aspace in the model. The %20 is not escaped and is just removed. I've also tried `http://localhost:8080/users/a+space` and the same thing happens.

Environment
Struts2 version, 2.3.15.1

Comment: It would depend on the ActionMapper implementation. Not sure about the default.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I took a look at DefaultActionMapper (I wasn't sure where the action name validating was happening) and saw what was happening to the action names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow spaces in action names by setting the parameter in the struts configuration,

```
struts.allowed.action.names
```

The default is

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._!/\-]*
```

The DefaultActionMapper uses this regex to validate the action name. If it doesn't match, it'll try to clean it up.

So modifying the setting to

```
<constant name="struts.allowed.action.names" value="[ a-zA-Z0-9._!/\-]*"/>
```

allows spaces